# Sql UPDATE STATEMENT oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update a quantity in to my database. I tried with a update statement, (trigger oracle, don't work because definitely something wrong)

My sql string is:

```
String sql1 = "update book set qty = qty - 1 where isbn='" + txt_carr.getText() + "'";
```

`txt_carr` is a txtField where I write a `isbn` (for add a cart), but the quantity don't change for that precise `ISBN`.

Also in the cart when you close the program, should update the quantity (even at a fixed, for example 5)

I tried this:

```
String sql3= "UPDATE book SET quantity= 5 (select isbn cart where isbn=) ";
```

Where `isbn` = to all isbn in your cart. So it should only update the quantity (in table book) of the books in the shopping cart and not all.

I know that a trigger would work much better, but do not know how to write it.

Comment: So what is this being called from?  Are you performing a commit?  What if you take your update string and run it from sqlplus or other sql client?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The trigger for me is difficult. that's why I just wanted to do an update of a sql command. It's possible?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Write error on the forum. the query is correct. but still does not work. update book set qty = qty - 1 where isbn='" + txt_carr.getText() + "'";   why don't update the quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE book b   SET b.quantity =
      (SELECT COUNT (*)
         FROM cards c
        WHERE c.isbn = b.isbn) WHERE b.isbn = 'YOUR_ISBN';
```

So your code will be as:

```
String sql1= "UPDATE book b SET b.quantity =(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM card c WHERE c.isbn = b.isbn) WHERE b.isbn = '" + txt_carr.getText() + "' ";
```

Not: I'm not sure about table names.

Comment: Thanks, i solved for set quantity=5. But the problem remains for the decrease in the amount based on the isbn inserted in txtField.

Comment: @neo999, where are you getting the amount you want subtracted from?

Comment: @neo999 can you post you error?  may be you have ROWLOCK before COMMIT or you "txt_carr" is null or txt_carr.getText() needs to be checked

Comment: PERFECT!!! the problem is txt_carr because is null at that time, I solved very very simply!!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax is not valid :

```
String sql3= "UPDATE book SET quantity= '5' where book.isbn = 'YOUR_ISBN'";
```

Comment: "YOUR ISBN"  Should take all the ISBN in table cart and restore the quantity in table book. how can I do? thanks